# Address text element on .qml

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside6

I would like to change a text in my gui. I can address the ListView element for which I have found a solution.

I would also like to address the text element arbitrarily and, for example, replace the text.

Also, I can't manage to address another ListView element with different content.

Here is my little program. Please excuse my English too
`main.py`

```
import sys
import vensoft_main
from time import sleep
import urllib.request
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide6.QtCore import QStringListModel, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import json
import sys
from typing import Text
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd 
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get our data
    url = "file:///Users/joerg/Documents/python/Rohertrag/rohertrag_fenster/output_heute.json"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
    
    # Format and sort the data
    data_list = list(data.values())
    
    # Set up the application window
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    view.update()

    # Expose the list to the Qml code
    my_model = QStringListModel()
    my_model.setStringList(data_list)
    view.setInitialProperties({"myModel": my_model}) 


    # Load the QML file
    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "view.qml"
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file.resolve()))
   
    # Show the window
    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)
    view.show()
    view.update()
   
    # execute and cleanup
    app.exec()
    del view
```

`new.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: root

        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            id: view_1

            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 25
            anchors.bottomMargin: 230
            anchors.rightMargin: 375
            model: manager.model

            delegate: Text {
                anchors.leftMargin: 50
                font.pointSize: 15
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                text: display
            }

        }

        Text {
            id: text1

            x: 486
            y: 46
            width: 127
            height: 118
            text: manager.text
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        ListView {
            id: view_2
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 25
            anchors.leftMargin: 25
            anchors.topMargin: 238
            anchors.rightMargin: 375
            delegate: Text {
                text: display
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                anchors.leftMargin: 50
                font.pointSize: 15
            }
            anchors.bottomMargin: 17
            model: manager.model
        }

        Text {
            id: text2
            x: 479
            y: 272
            width: 127
            height: 118
            text: manager.text
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

    }

    header: Label {
        color: "#15af15"
        text: qsTr("Wie ist den der Umsatz Heute?")
        font.pointSize: 17
        font.bold: true
        font.family: "Arial"
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        padding: 10
    }

}
```

[image: displayed window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Less is more, you don't need to place unnecessary imports, also you don't need data from external resources, a simple list is enough.</sub>

If you want to manipulate the QML view from python then it is better to create a QObject that has data as properties and export it to QML.

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import (
    Property,
    QDateTime,
    QObject,
    QStringListModel,
    QTimer,
    QUrl,
    Signal,
)
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication


class Manager(QObject):
    text_changed = Signal(name="textChanged")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = QStringListModel()
        self._text = ""

    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    @Property(str, notify=text_changed)
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, text):
        if self.text == text:
            return
        self._text = text
        self.text_changed.emit()


def main():
    # get our data
    data_list = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

    manager = Manager()

    # Set up the application window
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("manager", manager)
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)

    manager.model.setStringList(data_list)
    manager.text = "text"

    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "view.qml"
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file.resolve()))

    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)

    view.show()

    def handle_timeout():
        text = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()
        manager.text = text

    timer = QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=handle_timeout)
    timer.start()

    app.exec()
    del view


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: root

        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            id: view_1

            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 25
            anchors.rightMargin: 375
            model: manager.model

            delegate: Text {
                anchors.leftMargin: 50
                font.pointSize: 15
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                text: display
            }

        }

        Text {
            id: text1

            x: 486
            y: 46
            width: 127
            height: 201
            text: manager.text
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

    }

    header: Label {
        color: "#15af15"
        text: qsTr("Wie ist den der Umsatz Heute?")
        font.pointSize: 17
        font.bold: true
        font.family: "Arial"
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        padding: 10
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution! I have another small question.
How can I control several of the same elements?
I've expanded the .qml files so you know what I mean. Is this possible via the ID? text_1 text_2, view_1, view_2?